# Is there a way to backdate posts?

Tags: posts

Is there a way to backdate posts on WordPress?

The reason is that I am migrating content over from another site and want to keep their original publishing dates.

---

### Edit

The content is being migrated manually from a non-wordpress website

Comment: You've written a comment in both places saying you can't set a publish date to 2011.  Why not?  That's a standard feature of WordPress ... so are you getting an error?  Or is there another reason?  Both answers are sufficient for a typical WP installation, so without more info on why they don't work for you, there's not much more we can offer.

Comment: I have just reinstalled WordPress, and the year area is now there. No wonder I was confused about how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To manually edit publish date, click the Edit link in the Publish box when editing a post and set the date to whatever you'd like.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't WordPress preserve publish dates when using the import tool?

Comment: @StephenHarris - I imagine it would, though I have no experience with it personally. It wasn't clear how the content was being migrated.

Comment: @Milo edited question for clarity. I cannot backdate posts to 2011 in the WordPress publish menu

Comment: @Graeme Hutchison - what happens when you try, does the date not update? can you change month and day, just not year?

Comment: There's a difference between modification and creation date.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the date of any post to any time (setting it to the future will publish the post in the future at the date you set!) Here's what I mean:

If you go to edit a post, you should see this, and here is what to do as well:

[image]

Comment: I cannot set the date to a date in the past.